# Как подгрузить зависимые dll?

Tags: c#, .net

Есть сервис Scheduler, к которому необходимо подключить плагин. В app.config сервиса я добавил секцию плагинов. В плагине в post-build, прописал копирование dll `copy /Y "$(TargetDir)$(ProjectName).*"`. Все успешно копируется и берется при запуске сервиса. Но ему не хватает некоторых зависимостей(показал на рисунке). Я конечно могу в post-build плагина прописать копирование не хватающих. А если их 20? 20 строк копирования. 
Может есть какой то другой способ подгрузки таких зависимостей?

---

[image: Схема подключения плагина]

Comment: Если солюшн один на них, то просто укажите проект плагина как зависящий от основного проекта. Тогда плагин будет со всеми зависимостями копироваться при сборке.

Comment: Плагин делался для того, чтобы он подключался только когда он нужен. Если плагин не нужен, то никаких зависимостей в основном проекте не должно быть. Или может я вас не правильно понял? Как в VS сделать, то что вы описали?

Comment: А, ну моё предложение годится только для сборки. В плане логичности и связывания кода - будет криво, тут согласен. Тогда других хороших идей нет, надо пилить костыли по сборке, хоть простой bat-файл, хоть что-то посложнее